# Displaying validation Errors in form with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I've searched through several tutorials and answers to this forum to try to solve my problem: I want to show the validation errors from my bean in my form using spring MVC.

No matter what I try, I can't get it to work. Im not using redirections, my binding results are directly after the model class and so on.

Here's what I have so far:

Login Class:

```
public class LoginUser implements Serializable {

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="username", unique=true)
    @Size(min=5)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5)
    private String password;
```

Login Controller:

```
@Transactional
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    UserDao dao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "enter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doLogin(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid LoginUser user, BindingResult result, HttpSession session) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "login/loginForm";
        } else {
            if (dao.authenticate(user)) {
                session.setAttribute("userLoggedIn", user.getUsername());
                return "forward:index";
            } else {
                return "redirect:login";
            }
        }

    }
```

Login Form:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.css">
<title><spring:message code="title.login" /></title>
</head>
<body>
    <spring:message code="login.message.login" />
    <form:form action="enter" commandName="loginForm" method="POST">
        <spring:message code="username.login" />
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
        <form:errors path="username" />
        <spring:message code="password.login" />
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br /> <input
            type="submit" value="<spring:message code='button.login'/>"><br />
        <spring:message code="does.not.have.account.login" />
        <a href="register"><spring:message code="register.link.login" /></a>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Ohh, I forgot to add - I have a messages.properties configured (working fine, tested) and the messages are comming from there. Here is the line related to the form:

messages_en.Properties

```
NotEmpty.loginForm.username= Please fill the username field
```

By the way, it may be worth to note that my view is mounted trough a composite view (made of JSP includes of header, mainpage and footer) that overrides the customary viewloading in Sping-MVC.

Comment: I can suggest the way I did it. In my case I have for example such field in my user class `@Column
    @Pattern (regexp = "^[a-zA-Z_-]{2,30}$", message = "First name shall consist of 2-30 English letters")
    @NotEmpty (message = "First name is required.")
    private String firstName;
` and such respective code in jsp registration page `<label for="firstName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First name</label>
 <form:input path="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"/>
 <form:errors path="firstName" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/>
           `

Answer (score 0):

You are using `RedirectAttributes` but you are not redirecting user any where. Try to use `"redirect:/<register_path>"` or just add `Model model` to method params and use `model.addAtribute("someName", result);`

Comment: When I redirect, it also does not work (what is left on the code is rubbish from an earlier attempt). Also, tested the Model approach and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..

```
<form:form action="enter" commandName="loginForm" method="POST">
```

commandName is **loginForm** so  @ModelAttribute("loginForm").

```
@RequestMapping(value = "enter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doLogin( @Valid  @ModelAttribute("loginForm") LoginUser user, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model,  HttpSession session) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "login/loginForm";
        } else {
            if (dao.authenticate(user)) {
                session.setAttribute("userLoggedIn", user.getUsername());
                return "forward:index";
            } else {
                return "redirect:login";
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE :**

You are using `NotEmpty.loginForm.username= Please fill the username field` which is **wrong**,It should be **`NotNull.loginForm.username= Please fill the username field`**

And also

`@NotNull` will not validate for empty string..Request from the front end will be **`""`** which is not null.So use `@NotEmpty` instead.

If you **still want to use `@NotNull` add `InitBinder`** in your controller as shown below

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
}
```

Then it will validate for empty string.

That is the reason you are getting `size error` directly and since you have not mentioned any message for that no message is displaying.

Comment: Does not work either, Wanted to do it inside Spring for it would be waaaaay easyer. But its more complicated than expected.

Comment: What error exactly you are getting..bindingResult object has errors?? or it's not displaying in front end??

Comment: Not displaying on the front end... For example: empty username message is not appearing. Im guessing it has to do with the composite view that I made...

Comment: Binding result object has errors?? Can you show the binding result object content

Comment: I'm having the same error. I have applied the @NotNull constraint on a field, but it is not getting displayed when I run the jsp in the browser

Comment: @Nishil put a breakpoint at `result.hasErrors` and hover on bindingResult and copy paste that content here

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/RegisterStudent")
 String addStudent(@Valid Student sv, BindingResult bd) {

  if (bd.hasErrors()) {
   return "index";
  } else {
   ss.addStudent(sv);

   return "success";
  }
 }

Comment: Not the code...something like this..`org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'loginForm' on field 'username': rejected value [null]; codes [NotEmpty.loginForm.username,NotEmpty.username,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [loginForm.username,username]; arguments []; default message [username]]; default message [Please Enter User Name]`

Comment: And also show your spring-servlet.xml/application-servlet.xml

Comment: Im getting Field: Size
Error: Size
Field: Size
Error: Size
Field: username.empty
Error: username.empty
Field: password.empty
Error: password.empty

Comment: @Nishil your error is solved?? you can try the updated answer

Comment: the previous error got solved(I was able to successfully apply validations on the 'Add' form), but now the error is, that I am trying to apply validations on the update form, but the validation messages are not getting displayed

Comment: Where is your question?? post that link here

Comment: @PrasannaKumar will test later and post an answer.

Comment: @PrasannaKumar tested and it does not work either. As I said, it probably has a problem with the Composite View. It is not passing the errors to the template jsp, so they are not loading.

Comment: Have you changed to `NotNull.loginForm.username=`  because you were using @notNull

Comment: You should change to @NotNull..check the updated answer